# Unable to remove scrollbar in ionic 3

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, scrollbar, ionic3

I am not able to remove the scrollbar in iOS. The scrollbar shows up sometimes.

`::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display:none;
}`
didnt work.

tried to override using

`self.wkWebView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.wkWebView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;`

Even this didnt work.

This is only after using WKWebView. In UIWebView it was fine.
I don't want to remove wkWebView. I tested only in iPhone 6s - iOS 11. Didnt work in that

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am still searching

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the first answer, in my case I only had try adding to my app.css :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none !important;
}
```

so that it would be applied to all the app. When i tried with the * :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none !important;
}
```

it kind of solve the issue. In one of the scrolls it disappear, in another it didn't for a while, and then it did. Very strange. Enough for me, but definitely not a 100% solution.